# reading json file with std::eof while using nlohmann::json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I'm trying to read from JSON file with the while condition is the `std::eof`

but I'm getting the following exption :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'nlohmann::detail::parse_error'   what(): 
>   [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 1:
>   syntax error while parsing value - unexpected end of input; expected
>   '[', '{', or a literal

this is the file :

> [{"id":0,"price":0,"qty":0},{"id":1,"price":1,"qty":1}]

and this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <json.hpp>
#include <fstream>
using json = nlohmann::json;
int main() {
  std::ofstream f;
  f.open("test.json",std::ios_base::trunc |std::ios_base::out);
  json result = json::array();
  for(int i =0 ;i < 2 ; i++)
  {
    json j = {
        {"id",i},
        {"qty",i},
        {"price",i}
    };
    result.push_back(j);
  }
  f << result;
  f.close();
  std::ifstream j;
  std::string line;
  j.open("test.json",std::ios_base::in);
  json ob;
  while (!j.eof())
  {
    j>>ob;
    std::cout << ob << "\n";
  }
  j.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and break in the second loop, all should become clear.

Comment: I see that the while loop iterate one more time after the file ended but why is that happen?

Comment: Because `.eof()` is "set to true" only after you tried to read the end of the file. AFAIK, the `j>>ob` line is guaranteed to read the whole file the first time

Comment: @NadavS  tnx, I also figured your last comment and fix my code

Answer (score 0):

```
void from_json(std::ifstream& fin)
{
    json js;
    if (char ch = fin.get(); ch == ' ')
    {
        return;
    }
    while (fin.good())
    {
        fin.unget();
        fin >> js;
        std::cout << js;
        fin.get();
    }
}
```